# jquery shorttag issue

Tags: jquery, shorttags

```
<script>
$("#commentInfo").html("I m here");
</script>
```

if I have a standard start/end tag, then jquery is fine

```
<span id='commentInfo' class="commentInfo"></span>
Testing
```

output

```
I m here 
Testing
```

if I have shorttag

```
<span id='commentInfo' class="commentInfo"/>
```

it only displays

```
I m here
```

how could configure the jquery to support shorttag ?

Comment: What kind of shorttags do you have that need their `innerHTML` property set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short tags are closed. They are not meant to hold content or child elements. It's a self closing tag.

What you're trying to do is invalid.

Just stick to tags that open and close if you want child content and short tags if you don't need to add any child content to the HTML tag.